# Running 'ALTER TABLE TableName ENABLE TRIGGER TriggerName' for an already enabled trigger SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, triggers

Will running

```
ALTER TABLE TableName 
    ENABLE TRIGGER TriggerName
```

for an already enabled trigger have any impact on the table or trigger in SQL Server?

Answer (score 1):

It will acquire an exclusive Schema Lock (Sch-M) on the table, which is incompatible with any other table access.  Then it will discover that the trigger is already enabled and complete without making any changes.